# Family data file .familyxbak format help

Tags: ancestry.com, myheritage.com

I have data pertaining to my Grandmother's side of the family, it is saved as a `.familyxbak` file which I think is some sort of backup file downloaded from a genealogy website like myheritage.com or ancestry.com.

I am not familiar with this side of my family and was sent these files to add to a wider family tree so getting these to open would be super helpful, problem is... I can't.

Does anyone know what I can do to open such a file?

Is there software which will open it for me?

Software which can diagnose the file and give me information about it?

Or, is there a way of converting the file into a GEDCOM file?

Answer (score 3):

The `.familyx` extension appears to indicate a file created by [My Family Tree](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/index.htm) genealogy software for Windows. Their documentation lists [`.familyx`](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/myfamilytree/help/familyxfiles.htm) as the name of the file that represents

> a special container which packages all the family tree data, photos, stories, audio, videos, and attachments in a single file.

It's possible that someone saved their My Family Tree as a `.familyx` file and then manually renamed it to `.familyxbak`.

Another possibility is that someone used My Family Tree's "[Backup and Share](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/myfamilytree/help/backupandshare.htm)" feature, for which the documentation does not identify the file extension used. Maybe this feature creates the `.familyxbak` file.

In any case, it should be safe to retain the original `.familyxbak` as your backup, **copy** that file to a `.familyx` file in another directory/folder (so you have two files, the `.familyxbak` and the separate `.familyx`), and attempt to open the `.familyx` file in the My Family Tree software.

If something goes wrong, you still have the original `.familyxbak` unaltered.